# Moving a center of a rotation. (Decomposition of a rotation)

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, rotations, function-and-relation-composition

We denote:

- $R(a,\alpha)$ :"rotation about point $a$ by angle $\alpha$.
- $T_a$ : "translation" (e.g: $T_a(x)=x+a$).

I'm trying to simplify the composition of two rotations $R(a,\alpha)$ and $R(b,-\alpha)$.

But, I would like to clarify if one can move a center of a rotation.

More precisely, can $R(b,-\alpha)$ be inverted to a composition of rotation and translation? (i.e. decompose $R(b,-\alpha)$ with $R(a,\alpha)^{-1}$ and some translation.) So far, I have something like $R(b,\alpha)^{-1}=(T_{b-a}R(a,\alpha)T_{a-b})^{-1}$, but is there a simpler decomposition?

I'm hoping to get $R(a,\alpha)R(b,-\alpha)=T$ with some translation $T$ in terms of $a,  b$

P.S. Every map I'm talking about here are defined over a plane ($\mathbb{R}^2$)

Comment: A rotation with centre in the origin is represented by a rotation matrix \begin{pmatrix}
\cos\alpha & -\sin\alpha \\
\sin\alpha & \cos\alpha
\end{pmatrix}. The translation is done by just adding a translation vector. Check [1]


  [1]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix

Comment: If you turn your figures by $\alpha$ first, and then by $-\alpha$, you restore all the original directions, hence you get a translation. To find a vector of translation you just need to see how much the first rotation center was shifted by the second rotation (or how much the second rotation center was shifted by the first rotation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\mathcal A(E)$ be an affine plane over the vector space $E\;$ (therefore $\dim(E)=2).$

An *affine* rotation around the point $c$ and with angle $\theta$ is given, for all $p\in \mathcal A(E)$, by

$$ R(c, \theta)(p) = c + R_\theta(p-c) $$

where $R_\theta$ is the *vector* rotation with angle $\theta$ in $E$.

If $a$ and $b$ are any two points of $\mathcal A(E)$ and $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are any two angles, therefore, we have

\begin{align}
R(b,\beta)\circ R(a,\alpha)(p) &= R(b,\beta)(a+R_\alpha(p-a)) =\\[1ex]
&= b+R_\beta(a+R_\alpha(p-a)-b) =\\[1ex]
&= b+R_\beta(a-b)+R_\beta\circ R_\alpha(p-a).
\end{align}

If $\;\beta=-\alpha$, we then obtain

\begin{align}
R(b,-\alpha)\circ R(a,\alpha)(p) &=  b+R_{-\alpha}(a-b)+R_{-\alpha}\circ R_\alpha(p-a) =\\[1ex]
&= b+R_{-\alpha}(a-b)+p-a =\\[1ex]
&= p+(b-a)+R_{-\alpha}(a-b)
\end{align}

i.e. the translation with $\;b-a+R_{-\alpha}(a-b)\;$ as translation vector.